# Are ssh keys generated individually by Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 setup?

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh, security, encryption

Let's assume freshly installed and updated&upgraded Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with ssh server.

Does installation scripts generate new ssh keys for each installation (so I am safe having unique ones) ?
Or do I have to regenerate them manually after install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are generated after install during `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` stage. They are generated so there is no need to re-generate them.

This is well described by the [nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/) in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the host keys. These are generated through a postscript on installation and should be different on every server.